# Pagination in Cosmos DB using Page Size and Page Number

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, pagination, azure-cosmosdb, paging

I am trying to return items from cosmosDB using `PageSize` and `PageNumber`. I know we can set the page size in `MaxItemCount`, but how do we put the page number in this function?

Here's what I got so far:

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RunSQLQueryAsync(string queryString, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
        {
            var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = pageSize, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
            IQueryable<T> filter = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_collectionUri, queryString, feedOptions);
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();
            var currentPageNumber = 0;
            var documentNumber = 0;
            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (T t in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
                {
                    results.Add(t);
                    documentNumber++;
                }
                currentPageNumber++;
                return results;

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently, the **pagination support is based on continuation token only**.

Find below some interesting discussion and feature request about this limitation:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/377
- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6350987--documentdb-allow-paging-skip-take

---

**--- Continuation Token Example ---**

The following example illustrates a method (very similar to yours) that queries documents based on the desired page number, page size and continuation token:

```cs
    private static async Task<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<CeleryTask>>> QueryDocumentsByPage(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string continuationToken)
    {
        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://{CosmosDB/SQL Account Name}.documents.azure.com:443/"), "{CosmosDB/SQL Account Key}");

        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions {
            MaxItemCount = pageSize,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,

            // IMPORTANT: Set the continuation token (NULL for the first ever request/page)
            RequestContinuation = continuationToken 
        };

        IQueryable<CeleryTask> filter = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<CeleryTask>("dbs/{Database Name}/colls/{Collection Name}", feedOptions);
        IDocumentQuery<CeleryTask> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();

        FeedResponse<CeleryTask> feedRespose = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<CeleryTask>();

        List<CeleryTask> documents = new List<CeleryTask>();
        foreach (CeleryTask t in feedRespose)
        {
            documents.Add(t);
        }

        // IMPORTANT: Ensure the continuation token is kept for the next requests
        return new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<CeleryTask>>(feedRespose.ResponseContinuation, documents);
    }
```

Now, the following example illustrates how to retrieve documents for a given page by calling the previous method:

```cs
    private static async Task QueryPageByPage()
    {
        // Number of documents per page
        const int PAGE_SIZE = 3;

        int currentPageNumber = 1;
        int documentNumber = 1;

        // Continuation token for subsequent queries (NULL for the very first request/page)
        string continuationToken = null;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"----- PAGE {currentPageNumber} -----");

            // Loads ALL documents for the current page
            KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<CeleryTask>> currentPage = await QueryDocumentsByPage(currentPageNumber, PAGE_SIZE, continuationToken);

            foreach (CeleryTask celeryTask in currentPage.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{documentNumber}] {celeryTask.Id}");
                documentNumber++;
            }

            // Ensure the continuation token is kept for the next page query execution
            continuationToken = currentPage.Key;
            currentPageNumber++;
        } while (continuationToken != null);

        Console.WriteLine("\n--- END: Finished Querying ALL Dcuments ---");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I am not sure why, but when I set the page size to be 2, and the total items in cosmosDB is 5. For the first page, it returns 2 items - which is fine; then the next page, it returns 1 item for some weird reason; the 3d page, it returns 1 item again.. Any idea why? Thanks again!

Comment: `{"token":null,"range":{"min":"05C1C9CD673390","max":"05C1D399CD672C"}}` - it shows the token is null after the line `continuationToken = currentPage.Key;`

Comment: When the continuation token is **null**, it means there is no more documents available to read based on the query. I'll update the sample code to reflect that.

Comment: Shouldn't this skip if it's not on the correct page?

Comment: How to go to Previous Page ?

Comment: There is a limitation with using continuation tokens that they cannot be with cross partition queries. The query runs but header is not returned. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-node/issues/252#issuecomment-426357267.

Comment: I have added Order by, getting this token : [{\"compositeToken\":{\"token\":\"+RID:~WllDAJf2Rs4EAgAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:20#RTD:nReGcfWnOHBG6GZpH1ceBUJtY2pvAA==#ISV:2#IEO:65567#QCF:3#FPC:AgEAAAAqAE+AZADg7wEQEPj/AVEA8N8SQP+//v8RQLX/QUD3/xFA/98RQP7/EUD/Bw==\",\"range\":{\"min\":\"\",\"max\":\"FF\"}},\"orderByItems\":[{\"item\":\"Albin\"}],\"rid\":\"WllDAJf2Rs4EAgAAAAAAAA==\",\"skipCount\":0,\"filter\":\"true\"}]

But when unable to get next page  getting error as " Reason: (ParallelContinuationToken is missing field: 'token': {\"compositeToken\":{\"token\":\"

Comment: Where does the `pageNumber` come into play in `QueryDocumentsByPage`?

Comment: Chech this out: [OFFSET LIMIT clause in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/offset-limit) (posted on 10/12/2022)

Answer (score 22):

Skip & take is now available in Cosmos DB via a new OFFSET LIMIT clause:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be in the linked doc... [try here instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit)

Comment: Thanks, @Matt.  Microsoft apparently moved the documentation.

Comment: The offset-limit loads everything before applying pagination which defies the very purpose of pagination. We paginate to reduce loading time by not loading everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, but it is not optimal:

```
...
int pageNumber = 1;
int pageSize = 10;
...
    var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
                    new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = pageNumber * pageSize }) // Limit count or returned items
                    .Where(predicate)
                    .AsDocumentQuery();

                var results = new List<T>();
                int resultsToSkip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();

                    // Skip pages, not optimal way, the best solution is to use RequestContinuation token.
                    if (resultsToSkip > 0)
                    {
                        resultsToSkip--;
                        continue;
                    }

                    results.AddRange(result);
                }

                return results;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

public  static List pagination(int pageNo=1,int pageSize=20)
    {
        List ArticlesList = new List();
        var collection = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, loginCollectionId);

```
    using (client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), primaryKey))
    {

        var optionss = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = (pageNo!=1)?((pageNo-1)*pageSize): ((pageNo) * pageSize)
        };

        var query1 = client.CreateDocumentQuery<ArticlesListDetails>(collection, optionss).OrderByDescending(x => x._ts).AsDocumentQuery();

        var res = query1.ExecuteNextAsync<ArticlesListDetails>().Result;
        if (pageNo == 1)
        {
            return   ArticlesList = res.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            var options = new FeedOptions
            {
                MaxItemCount = pageSize,
                RequestContinuation = res.ResponseContinuation
            };

            var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<ArticlesListDetails>(collection, options).OrderByDescending(x => x._ts).AsDocumentQuery();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                return  ArticlesList = query.ExecuteNextAsync<ArticlesListDetails>().Result.ToList();
            }
        }

        return ArticlesList;
    }

}
```