# Cosmos DB pagination leading to "Request rate is large" exceptions

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have implemented a class to read from Cosmos DB using the `MongoDB.Driver.IMongoClient`.

I need pagination as there are a large number of items in each collection, I thought I had achieved this with the following:

```
private async Task<ICollection<SomeClass>> ReadMessages(IMongoCollection<SomeClass> collection, FilterDefinition<SomeClass> filter, int page, int pageSize)
{
    var found = new List<SomeClass>();

    using (var cursor = await collection
        .Find(filter)
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
        .Limit(pageSize)
        .ToCursorAsync())
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            var batch = cursor.Current;

            found.AddRange(batch.Select(x => x);
        }
    }

    return found.ToArray();
}
```

We're now running into "Request rate is large" exceptions for higher page numbers.

From what I can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164399/pagination-in-cosmos-db-using-page-size-and-page-number) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/issues/377) Cosmos DB doesn't support `Skip` so would anybody be able to explain what `IMongoClient` is doing here?

Also, what is the correct way to achieve this using a continuation token?

Comment: I suspect the first question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120109/3181933), and given it has to go through the Mongo driver, I'm wondering if perhaps there isn't a solution here.

Comment: Since `skip` is not a native function for Cosmos DB's SQL API, the MongoDB API will likely have the same limitations (e.g. MongoDB's `skip` possibly being implemented via paging in the background). What is your collection's current RU scale? If you're returning a significant amount of documents, you might have to increase RU.

Comment: Also note: The MongoDB client knows nothing of specific implementation, since it's a standard MongoDB client. It knows nothing of Cosmos DB; it just talks with the MongoDB API endpoint, as it would with any other MongoDB database.